# Нумерация строк по результату выборки из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы. В обеих таблицах есть одинаковые столбцы с одинаковым значением.
Есть код

```
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, place, nick, authid, 
((frags-headshots)* 1+ headshots* 1+ (explode + defused + hostages)* 3+ (explode + defused + hostages)* 3 + c.cms_addxp) AS sort, c.cms_addxp AS cxp, w.cms_addxp AS wxp
FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t, csstats_players c 
INNER JOIN csstats_extra_stats w USING(authid)
ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Делаю нумерацию строк с последующей ее записью в столбец- num будет записан в place. Сортировка строк по столбцу sort

Проблема в следующем.
Если в сортировке использовать значение из таблицы `c` (`c.cms_addxp`), получаем **нужный** результат, где num присвоен по убыванию значения sort
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если использовать значение из другой таблицы `w` (`w.cms_addxp`), то получается непонятный результат

```
`hostages)* 3 + w.cms_addxp) AS sort`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за этого неверно устанавливается колонка place.

Comment: Если хотите использовать переменные, забудьте про JOIN. Источником данных должна быть строго одна таблица, подзапрос или представление, или гарантированно получится наблюдаемая хрень. А если версия MySQL восьмая, то используйте оконную функцию и не корячьтесь с переменными вообще. *Если в сортировке использовать значение из таблицы c (c.cms_addxp), получаем нужный результат ... Но, если использовать значение из другой таблицы w (w.cms_addxp), то получается непонятный результат* Случайность, зависящая от построенного плана выполнения запроса. В любой момент может перевернуться.

Comment: Спасибо. Сортировка работает, но тогда, со вложенным запросом не получается обновить столбец в таблице, из которой была выборка
UPDATE `csstats_players` SET place=(SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1)
FROM
    (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t, csstats_players c
    ORDER BY ((frags-headshots)* 1+ headshots* 1+ (explode + defused + hostages)* 3+ 
(explode + defused + hostages)* 3 + (SELECT `cms_addxp` FROM `csstats_extra_stats` WHERE authid=c.authid)) DESC
LIMIT 5);

Comment: *со вложенным запросом не получается обновить столбец в таблице, из которой 
была выборка* Неправильно обновляетесь. В коррелируемом подзапросе всегда есть дополнительный неявный источник данных - использованная внешняя таблица. А, как я сказал выше, таблица должна быть одна. Используйте multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Comment: For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Comment: А это здесь каким боком? Подзапрос, в котором будет ORDER BY - он SELECT, и в нём хоть качучу пляши.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный рабочий запрос

```
UPDATE `csstats_players` r SET place=(SELECT @a:=@a+1 FROM (SELECT @a:=0) s) 
ORDER BY (frags-headshots)* 1+ headshots* 1+ (explode + defused + hostages)* 3+ (explode + defused + hostages)* 3 + 
(SELECT `cms_addxp` FROM `csstats_extra_stats` WHERE authid=r.authid) DESC;
```

Comment: *Правильный рабочий запрос* Рабочий (до поры до времени) - да. Правильный - нет.

Comment: Что здесь не так? Можно ли пример посмотреть?

Comment: Если есть нумерующий запрос `SELECT .. FROM t .. ORDER BY .., id`, то обновляющий запрос будет `UPDATE t JOIN (SELECT .. FROM t .. ORDER BY .., id) t1 USING (id) SET t1.col = t1.col`.

Comment: *Что здесь не так?* Да он тупо недетерминированный - о чём ещё говорить?